# Analytically understanding wireless power transfer

Tags: electromagnetism, wireless, inductance, resonance

https://youtu.be/M8aZoM9p43k

This YouTube link shows a experiment I quickly made.
 
 Two resonant lc circuits that use magnetic fields to wirelessly light up a led. I manually found the best frequency after finding the inductance using a LCR meter. Its low frequency, so like 200kHz. No impedance matching. My two main questions are:
 Is there a way to analytically solve for the power received. I know inductance, frequency, coil size, wire size, etc. Also, can you calculate for power received when a foreign similar coil is placed wirelessly in between the sending and receiving coil. If you watch the link, you see it increases power transfer. It can also decrease the power transfer. Im guessing because it changes inductance and throws off resonance. Is there a general equation for power transfer as a function of distance, inductive loops, frequency, etc. 
Also, from my experiment, a square wave works much better than a sin wave and the signal received in the oscilloscope is sin wave, even though im sending a square wave. Is there math to explain the square wave working better(found experimentally) and the signal received is a sinusoid?
Thank you

Comment: You are recieving a sine wave because the LC circuit acts as a filter, letting through only the resonant frequency and eliminating the harmonics. Remember that a square wave is the sum of a fundamental sine wave plus odd harmonics, which are sine waves too.

Comment: Very interesting. Since this is one of my main questions could you maybe share a little more on how a lc circuit is only allowing the resonant sine wave through. Is it like a lc band pass filter? Also, any explanation why the square wave generated a higher received voltage? When i switched to its counterpart pure sin wave, the led went noticeably dimmer.

Comment: I don't know exactly how your circuit is wired but I would guess its acting like a Band Pass filter, leaving only the resonant frequency go through. Regarding the square wave, a square wave has higher RMS value than a sinewave, plus, remember that the induction in the reciever is directly proportional to the rate of change of the magnetic field produced by the signal, a square wave has sharper transitions than a sine wave, thus higher rate of change.

Comment: I thought that. Like the fast edge of the square pulse causes a magnetic filed that "hits" the receiver circuit with a stronger magnetic field. Im going to look into the rms of a square wave. Thank you. The circuit is a capacitor in parallel with a inductor (the large coils)

Comment: Yeap, that sounds like the typical tank circuit to me, remember that the circuit resonates at a frequency and that frequency is the one propagated to the reciever which is also tuned to that frequency. If you know the capacitance and the inductance you can calculate the resonant frequency and see if it agrees with the one you found experimentally

Comment: That's how I guessed a resonant frequency. I knew inductance and with my capacitor value using c = 1/(f^2 * 4pi^2 * L) I found resonance around 180kHz. My circuit was about 30kHz off. (which I don't know if that's an expected error?) So the non resonant frequencies of the square wave create power that ends up being lost to the impedance of the circuit?

Comment: How did you find the resonant frequency experimentally? you may also have to consider mutual inductance.,

Comment: It's not like radio where power is transmitted and the receiver "grabs" that power hence there is no power transfer equation like radio. Power taken depends on the load and the coils inefficiencies.

Comment: adjusting the frequency one kHz at a time and watching the led get brighter

Comment: AFAIK, you cannot determine analytically the coupling factor (maybe with FEM), only through measurements, but it affects the values of the primary and secondary inductances and, thus, the resonant frequency (and the level): [test run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TxcL.png). You can see how the peak of the red trace goes above the pink trace, despite the pink level being higher. Also, because the fundamental + harmonics of the square wave are fixed, the resonance falls between these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming perfect impedance matching, power transfer efficiency for two resonators is given by:
$$\eta = \frac{k^2 Q_1 Q_2}{1 + \sqrt{1+k^2 Q_1 Q_2}}$$
Where k is the magnetic coupling coefficient and Q is the unloaded quality factor of resonator 1 and 2, respectively. If you have no impedance matching, I reccomend equation 3 given in this witricity white paper on WPT (https://witricity.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/White_Paper_20161218.pdf). That equation can be modified if you know your source and generator impedance.

The coupling coefficient is given by
$$k=\frac{L_m}{\sqrt{L_1 L_2}}$$
Where Lm is the mutual inductance and L1 and L2 are the inductances of each coil. Analytical expressions for mutual inductance for two loops do exist, but it's often simpler to just measure mutual inductance with your LCR meter. You can estimate it with:
$$L_m = \frac{\mu_0 \pi}{2} \frac{r_1^2 r_2^2}{(z^2 + r_1^2)^{3/2}} $$
Assuming that r1 > r2. I got the formula based on the lectures here: [http://www.pas.rochester.edu/~dmw/phy217/Lectures/Lect_35b.pdf](http://www.pas.rochester.edu/%7Edmw/phy217/Lectures/Lect_35b.pdf)
There are other formulas for more general coils, but it will get considerably complicated quickly.

Lastly you need some method for estimating Q factor. The quality factor for a resonator is typically dominated by the inductor, unless you have some other large source of loss in your capacitor. This is given by:
$$Q = \frac{\omega_0 L}{R_s}$$
$$\omega_0 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{LC}}$$
Where w0 is the angular resonant frequency and Rs is the series resistance of your coil, measurable with your LCR meter. There are also analytical expressions for Rs, but I suggest just measuring it if you can. Putting all that together should give you an idea of power transfer efficiency as a function of coil geometry and separation distance. You'll notice that for a very efficient system efficiency is typically proportional to k, which is proportional to Lm, which drops on the order of an inverse cube. The idea that WPT efficiency in inductive systems drops on the order of R^-3 is a common rule of thumb for inductive systems.

That witricity white paper is probably one of the best open resources on the theory of inductively coupled systems without getting too complicated, if you are interested in further reading.